# DoS attack to device not connected to WiFi

Tags: wifi, attacks, denial-of-service

I would like to know if there is any attack to DoS a device (NOT AN AP) that is not connected to any WiFi network. Using Probe Request frames I can obtain the MAC address.

I can't 802.11 deauth attack (aireplay) because, as I said, the device is not connected to any WiFi. About MDK3, I think I can't use it either.

Any ideas on what can I do?

Thank you.

Edit with some interested things commented below:

Imagine I have a WiFi network and I want to prevent from attacks. If I see a MAC address unknown to me, what can I do to exhaust this device resources (it can be for example a laptop with a Realtek or Ralink NIC) so it can't generate any kind of traffic that maybe could affect my network? The idea is send some kind of 802.11 packet (maybe hundreds of pkts) and do not allow him to disrupt my network.

Comment: If the device is not connected, it means that no service is running which can be denied.

Comment: @defalt Ok, so is there any way to disrupt the functionality of the device? I mean, while this attack is running, block this device to try to connect to any wifi, block it to send any kind of frames.

Comment: Of course there is. An attacker can set up hundreds of fake access points with the same SSID as in your surroundings, thus preventing you to choose which one is real. Another attack **Broadpwn** vulnerability was introduced in [Blackhat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDk2RId8LFo) which can crash your kernel as shown in the conference just by leaving the wifi on.

Comment: My idea was in the other direction, imagine I have a WiFi network and I want to prevent from attacks. If I see a MAC address unknown to me, what can I do to exhaust this device resources (it can be for example a laptop with a Realtek or Ralink NIC) so it can't generate any kind of traffic that maybe could affect my network? The idea is send some kind of 802.11 packet (maybe hundreds of pkts) and do not allow him to disrupt my network.

Comment: @elena.bdc it would be useful to include this context in your question

Comment: @elena.bdc I'm not sure any of your neighbours will be very happy that you DoS all their devices all of the time ....

Comment: @schroeder I will edit it. Hahaha don't worry about my neighbours, this if for my Bachelor Final Project :P

Comment: You need a jammer to interfere with the traffic coming out of your attacker's device but jammer works in a radius and not like a beam so it affects your network too and gets you arrested. Doesn't that make you an attacker?

Comment: If you want to do this in 802.11 way then only known potential attack is **Broadpwn** which is a Remote code execution exploit and can attack just by leaving the phone's wifi on. But it only works on unpatched Broadcom wifi chip.

Comment: I will try it and I will post a feedback then. Thank you @defalt for all your help :)